# How to find the attribute when receiving an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

When using strong_params and getting an `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` exception, how do I find out which attribute is forbidden? I've just switched from `attr_accessible` and the debug message was normally pretty good there but not when switching to strong params.

I receive this error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in SnippetsController#create
```

This is a nested model.

```
def snip_params
  params.require(:snippet).permit(:content, :approved, :user_id, :book_id)
end
```

In the parent I've used

```
has_nested_attributes :snippets
```

The create

```
def create
  @snippet = @book.snippets.create(snip_params)
  @snippet.user = current_user
  if @snippet.save
    redirect_to @book
    flash[:success] = "Snippet submitted and awaiting approval."
  else
    flash[:base] = "Someone else has submitted a snippet, please try again later"
    redirect_to @book
  end
end
```

Params Contents:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"bTRSwFRIhN3l3DkkWPtLzpoQHYD+CezmJQLw8Oz5+3g=",
 "snippet"=>{"content"=>"<p>AAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>\r\n"},
 "commit"=>"Create Snippet",
 "book_id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: it's seems to me you can see a Warning in the log with list of params

Answer (score 2):

All attributes are forbidden initially. This exception is only raised when you don't permit any attributes. If you permit some and not others, then the log output tells you which parameters were not permitted.

```
 params = ActionController::Parameters.new(name: 'Bob', age: 24) 
 #params are usually set automatically in the controller
 Person.new(params)
```

The above will raise the exception

```
 Person.new(params.permit(:name))
```

This will create a person with name 'Bob', the log output will also contain:

```
Unpermitted parameters: age
```

Comment: can't reproduce that error, I don't think it has to do with nesting, since you are providing the attributes directly. Can you post what the contents of params is when you get the error?

Comment: I'm stumped. The only way I can get that exception to raise is by not calling permit on the params hash.

Comment: The only place in the rails code where that exception is raised is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/activemodel/lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb)

Comment: I guess it is not seeing the .new(snip_params) then, question is why?

Comment: I would suggest taking the require/permit code out of that function call and putting it directly into the create call

Comment: I even tried creating the snippet in the console IRB and it committed and passed...

Answer (score 1):

They are logged into DEBUG level: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/lib/strong_parameters/log_subscriber.rb